# How to grep text for small mistakes

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

Using standard Unix tools how can I search in a text file or output for a word with maybe 1-2 letters transposed or missed?

For example my input

```
function addtion(number, increment)
  return number+increment
end

function additoin(number, increment)
  return number+increment
end
```

I would like to search for `addition` and match `addtion` and `additoin` in my input and tell me about it. Because it's code, checking against dictionary is out of the question.

Currently `cat file.txt | grep "addition"` will simply yield me nothing.

Comment: With grep, the only thing you can search for words which starts with 'ad' or 'a' and ends with 'n', and possible character set inbetween. For that you can do something like `grep -En "a[dito]+n" file --color`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can play around with the [`agrep`](https://www.tgries.de/agrep/) command. It can perform fuzzy, approximate matches.

The following command worked for me:

```
agrep -2 addition file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a fuzzy match with standard grep, but if there are specific misspelling you're interested in, you could construct a regular expression that matches those.

For example:

```
 grep add[it]*on
```

matches the example misspelling you gave. But that's probably not general enough for your purposes.

A better approach is likely going to be to use some sort of static analysis tool specific to the language the code is in. It might not give you the right spelling, but should be able to tell you where the function name and calls to the function use different spellings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [spell](http://www.linfo.org/spell.html) command. Note: You might need a dictionary (usually `aspell-en` in your distro's repositories).

Answer (score -1):

Try this on linux terminal:

grep -rnw "text" ./